# Docusign download unsigned enveloppe with tabs

Tags: docusignapi

Hello I'm using the docusign rest api and I have a use case where I must download an envelope document in pdf for manual signing the problem is when an envelope isn't signed I get the envelope document empty (without pre-filled fields) but when it's signed I get the document with all the fields,
the result expected is the document with all pre-filled fields.
Here is my code:

```
    $curl = curl_init($loginInfo['baseUrl'] . "/envelopes/" . 'f487cf56-3a07-4cd3-ace7-XXXXXXXXXXXX' . "/documents" );
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
            "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )
    );
    $json_response = curl_exec($curl);
    $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
    if ( $status != 200 ) {
        echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
        exit(-1);
    }

    $response = json_decode($json_response, true);
    curl_close($curl);
    //var_dump($xml);

    //
    // STEP 3 - download the documents
    //
    foreach( $response["envelopeDocuments"] as $document ) {
        print_r($document);
        $docUri = $document["uri"];

        $curl = curl_init($loginInfo['baseUrl'] . $docUri );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                "X-DocuSign-Authentication: $header" )
        );
        $data = curl_exec($curl);
        $status = curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
        if ( $status != 200 ) {
            echo "error calling webservice, status is:" . $status;
            exit(-1);
        }

        file_put_contents('f487cf56-3a07-4cd3-ace7-XXXXXXXX' . "-" . $document["name"], $data);
        curl_close($curl);
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For people searching, you can't do it until the envelope is completed, the fields aren't attached to the document until it's signed.